# Override Python Exception Message

Tags: python, exception, logging

I want to add *additional* information to exception output globally in my application.  I do not want to have to try/catch every function, and redundantly adjust the message there. I want to adjust the message on the exception itself such that it gets applied everywhere automatically.

Trivial Example:

```
>>> i = 1 / 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

And it clearly prints the message `division by zero`. Suppose I had a function `get_hostname()` that told me my public IP address.  I want this to now output `division by zero | 11.22.33.44`.  Again, I don't want to wrap the offending line in a try/catch, I want to change the functionality of this Exception itself.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this without a `try/except` of some sort.  Can't even overwrite the default `Exceptions` if you wanted to.  Do you have a [mcve] that demonstrates how you would want to achieve the output anyhow? Not sure how that output is supposed to come from `get_hostname()`.

Comment: Just raise a ZeroDivisionError('division by zero | 11.22.33.44') if the divisor is equal to zero

Comment: @spadarian you'd need a `try/except` for that, which OP is asking to not use (not that I agree with).

Comment: Not really... I assume that the `get_hostname()` has a line like `something / divisor`... you just need an if statement before that line.

Comment: @spadarian try it.  You'll always get the `ZeroDivisionError` before you can move on from that line.  If you don't catch it, the program ends at that point.

Comment: The idea is not to avoid raising the error, just changing the message. You can just raise the error before the `something / divisor` line is evaluated.

Comment: You could try to override `ZeroDivisionError` with a subclass of the same name, but I'm not sure how to make that the class used *everywhere*.

Answer (score 0):

No idea how your function works but you are dividing `something` by a `divisor`:

I would definitely try to catch the exception or use an if statement if you know the `divisor` can be zero:

```
def get_hostname():
    divisor = 0
    something = 1
    if divisor == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError('division by zero | 11.22.33.44')
    return something / divisor
```

Other option is to use a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def extra_info(ip):
    def dec(f):
        def _decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                ans = f(*args, **kwargs)
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                raise ZeroDivisionError('division by zero | {}'.format(ip))
            return ans
        return wraps(f)(_decorator)
    return dec


@extra_info('11.22.33.44')
def get_hostname():
    divisor = 0
    something = 1
    return something / divisor
```